# Linux read() minimum data amount

Tags: c, linux, unix

When using read() syscall in Linux for reading from whatever source (file, socket, pipe), is there a minimum data amount that can be returned (in blocking mode)? Or can the syscall even return 1 byte?

When I want to read a single int (4 or 8 bytes) from a pipe, do I still need to check the return value of read() to see if I received less than sizeof(int) bytes?

Comment: In practice, doing one `read(2)` syscall for every word or byte is not efficient. You should buffer your reads (with a buffer size of e.g. 1K - 128K bytes), or use a library (e.g. `<stdio.h>` with `fread`) doing the buffering for you.

Comment: I want to use it for IPC, where I only need to send one int to another process.

Comment: But you can still read a larger amount. There might be cases where you'll have more than once int to read (e.g. if your process wasn't scheduled often enough, because the system is too busy, and/or the other writing process is spilling out data at a fast rate into the pipe).

Comment: In my scenario, process A sends one int to B and *waits* for response, which is also one int. Process B read()s on the pipe and expects one int, does some processing and sends a result (one int).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no minimum, except on block mode devices where the minimum is the block size.

You should always check the return value; things can break, you should plan for breakage and handle short reads and errors appropriately instead of assuming the other side is always perfect.

Comment: Even when reading from block devices you can read a smaller amount, it's just that the OS will read a whole block from the underlying device, but not return all the data to you.